# ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 –inline

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web

I am following [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/) as tutorial, upon hitting start to the build, I am getting the following error

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '–inline' in 'D:\aaa\vvv'

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 –inline
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '–inline' in 'D:\aaa\vvv'
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 –inline main[1]
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

what should I do to resolve it?

Comment: try --inline in cmd instead of -inline

Comment: @HaseebEqx now I get ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '–-inline' in 'D:\aaa\vvv'

Comment: What was the command you gave?

Comment: @HaseebEqx my bad, I was giving the wrong command, but now that I have given the write command ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --inline, I get Error: The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.

Comment: @HaseebEqx could help me in resolving this please?

Comment: Change loader to `babel-loader` instead of `babel`

Comment: I did @HaseebEqx but am getting Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.   I would add my babel.config.js for better understanding